# How do I insert a background image for the title page in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, r, reveal.js

I am having some trouble inserting a background image in the title page. I used to use io_slides to create rmarkdown presentations. In io_slides, I only needed the following codes in my CSS file to insert background image for the title page and the subsequent pages.

```
slide.title-slide{ background-image:('Title.jpg');}
```

for the title page, and

```
slide { background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%; 
background-image: url('Slide.jpg');}
```

for the subsequent pages.

How do I do this in reveal.js?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the markup to see what you should attach your css selectors too?

Comment: @gforce301 Hi, sorry. I do not know what you meant by inspecting the markup.

Comment: reveal.js runs in a browser, yes? Browsers display markup, also know as html. The javascript creates the markup (html) so the browser has something to display. Have you looked at the html that is created?

Comment: Hi, yes. I do not think reveal.js is reading my css file at all. Is there a different way to alter the background? I am using R studio by the way.

Answer (score 1):

[Official documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#slide-backgrounds)

Slides are contained within a limited portion of the screen by default to allow them to fit any display and scale uniformly. You can apply full page backgrounds outside of the slide area by adding a data-background attribute to your  elements. Four different types of backgrounds are supported: color, image, video and iframe.

Comment: This works fine for most slides. But how to do it for the *title slide*?